# assert not working the way i thought in java

Tags: java

I am new to java.. so maybe thats why I am not getting the keyword right?

So.. I wrote a quick class from that bank customer example.. and one of the method is withdraw.

```
public void withdraw(double d){
        double diff = balance - d;
        assert (diff>=0 ) :" Insufficient funds!";
        balance = diff;
    }
```

So what I was intending was if the withdraw abount is greater than the balance.. then throw up an error... (which i think should be more like an exception .... but lets say i want to check this by assertion)...

But it doesnt do anything.. even though when diff is less than zero..

the code compiles fine.. whereas I was expecting it to throw up an error.

What am i doing wrong

Comment: If the pre-condition for the method is: "any withdraw amount" then your use of assertion is not correct. It is correct if pre-condition is "<= balance"

Comment: You might also want to ensure that a negative amount or NaN is not withdrawn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assertions are disabled by default. You can enable all assertions by passing the -enableassertions flag when invoking the JVM.

[Edit]

You can find the Java Programming with Assertions guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html). Note the bit on enabling and disabling assertions.

Comment: When you run the `java` command, add `-enableassertions` immediately after the `java` bit

Comment: Is there a way to configure eclipse?

Comment: @Fraz In eclipse: Run -> Run Configurations -> Arguments (tab) -> VM arguments -> type `-ea` or `-enableassertions`

Comment: You can also easily add to all JUnit tests by going to Java > JUnit in your Eclipse preferences and checking the "add -ea to VM arguments"

Answer (score 5):

Assertions are not enabled by default, you need to explicitly enable them when you run your java application, e.g.

```
java -ea SomeClass
```

Comment: @Hansanein.. I am using eclipse.. how do i enable it in eclipse?

Comment: from within eclipse, right click the class you want to run then choose run as > run configurations > arguments tab then inside the JVM options enter -ea